# Replacing part of jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I'm working on a shopping cart for a fabric store, and the fabric is sold by 1/2 yards. However, the shopping cart displays the quantity in whole integers by default. I need to find a way to get this to display correctly. For instance:

A quantity of 1 would actually display as "1/2 yard", 
2 would display as "1 yard", 
3 would display as "1 1/2 yards", 
etc

Right now I have this:

```
var qty = $('.form-input--incrementTotal').val();

var qtyNew = (qty / 2);
```

I know I could say:

```
if (qtyNew == '.5') {
    qtyNew = '1/2';
}
```

And repeat that for every quantity that would contain a half yard, but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way. Is there a way to search qty for .5 and replace the .5 with 1/2, so 3.5 would be changed to 3 1/2 without me having to make an if statement for each quantity?

Comment: do `qtyNew % 1 ? "1/2" : "" ` if you know that it only will be decimals .0 and .5

Comment: @bigless that worked, thank you!